# Visual indicator when a float is too tall

Tags: floats

In draft mode, LaTeX prints a black marker if text can't be wrapped and it extends into the margin (overfull hbox). Is it possible to have a similar visual indicator if a float is too tall for the page, and extends into the footer area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX makes a warning in the log, you can make it print something at the same time:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter


\def \@largefloatcheck{%
  \ifdim \ht\@currbox>\textheight
    \@tempdima -\textheight
    \advance \@tempdima \ht\@currbox
    \@latex@warning {Float too large for page by \the\@tempdima}%
    \global\setbox\@currbox\hbox{%
      \box\@currbox
      {\color{red}\smash{\llap{FLOAT TOO BIG}}\vrule width 5pt}}%
    \ht\@currbox \textheight
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\rule{2cm}{19cm}
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\smash` here is added to fix the issue raised in comments that the original code could loop for some fonts. Without `\smash` I was assuming that the uppercase text `FLOAT TOO BIG` would have no depth, but the font metrics of some fonts do give capitals non zero depth.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'd like, unfortunately it doesn't work when I put it into my document.

`
    Chapter 9.
    (./parts/appendix.tex [81]
    ! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
    \clearpage ...rite \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty -\@Mi`

Comment: @Åsmund that's odd I don't see how that definition can change the formatting at all (apart from the added text, which should just over-print and not affect anything else)

Comment: Seems the error occurs when *some* font-packages are loaded. For example, fontspec, fourier, pxfonts, txfonts, all trigger this, but not lmodern or concrete. Related to font format?

Comment: @Åsmund OK thanks I can reproduce, i'll post a fix, perhaps this evening

Comment: @Åsmund try now

Answer (score 2):

The overfull rule works for horizontal boxes only.

Violations into the footer area can also be seen more easily, if there is a box around the body area. Package `geometry` marks the page layout with boxes, if it is uses with option `showframe`. If `geometry` is not uses otherwise, then option `pass` notifies `geometry` to not touch the layout parameters:

```
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}
```